# java swing - layout oddness when using different layout managers

Tags: java, swing, layout

Bit of oddness, seen if I do the following:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class FunkyButtonLayout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        JPanel j0 = new JPanel();     // j0 gets added to the root pane
        j0.setLayout(null);
        JPanel j1 = new JPanel();     // j1 gets added to j0 
        j1.setLayout(null);
        JButton b1 = new JButton(""); // b1 gets added to j1
        j1.add(b1);
        b1.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 32);   // b1 is big
        j0.add(j1);
        j1.setBounds(0, 0, 32, 32);   // j1 is not so big - b1 gets 'trimmed'
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null); // <- seems to be needed :-(
        frame.getContentPane().add(j0);             
        j0.setBounds(10, 10, 32, 32); // end result: a 32x32 button with
        frame.setSize(125, 125);      // a trimmed right border
        frame.setVisible(true);       // in the top-left corner
    }
}
```

I get pretty much what I'm looking for, apart from the ability to position j0 in the root pane with a layout manager. If I change the

```
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

line to

```
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
```

I see j0 draw as a 1x1 pixel @ the middle of the screen :-(

Any ideas why? Note that this isn't just a FlowLayout thing - pretty much every layout manager messes this up.

I really want to have the net effect of the 'border trimmed on one side' button - it allows me to do the toolbar-button-cluster thing (the kind of thing that [cage fighter](http://www.otierney.net/cagefighter/) tries to get rid of) with native-looking button controls - I cannot see another way of doing this, thanks to OS-level skins. So any ideas appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the layout manager to null, you have to explicitly set the container's preferred size (that's why it's showing up so small).

If you are using setBounds on a component, you are over-riding the work that the layout manager for the parent container does.

I would remove all calls to setBounds and all calls to setLayout(null) and try to achieve the effect you are after using just layout managers.

Comment: You da man! Well, almost ;-) "using the layout managers the way they were intended to be used" doesn't buy me the hack I'm looking for.

However adding  j0.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32, 32)); after the j0.setBounds line resolves the issue. 

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

> *...any ideas why ?*

Yes. That happens because when you remove the layout manager ( by setting it to null ) you're saying to the computer "I'll to all the laying work"; while using any other LayoutManager will attempt to ... well  layout your components according to your needs ( based on the properties of the objects to be lay-ed )

So, I think it would be much better to instead try to create a Border instance and set it into the JButton instead of trying to tweak all the objects around it.

I'll see if I can came up with something quickly.

**EDIT:**

Oops, it wasn't any quick, but here it is ( I messed up with a 1px line that was annoying me ) 

[alt text http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8933/capturaby8.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8933/capturaby8.png)

As I said before, setting the layout to null is not the best approach. Better is to create a custom border and set it to the button ( or set null border ).

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

/**
 * Sample usage of swing borders.
 * @author <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/20654">Oscar Reyes</a>
 */
public class ButtonBorderSample  { 

    public static void main( String [] args )  { 

        // Pretty standard swing code
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );


        JPanel panel  = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( 
                                       FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 5 ) );


        panel.add( createButton( "F I R S T" ) );
        panel.add( createButton( "S E C O N D" ) );
        panel.add( createButton( "T H I R D " ) );

        frame.add( panel , BorderLayout.NORTH );

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );

    }
    /**
     * Utility method to create a button.
     * Creates the button, make it square, and add our custom border.
     */
    private static JButton createButton( String s ) { 
        JButton b = new JButton( s );
        b.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 100, 100   ) );
        b.setBorder( new NoGapBorder() );
        return b;
    }
}

/**
 * This border implementation. It doesn't have insets and draws only a 
 * few parts of the border 
 * @author <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/20654">Oscar Reyes</a>
 */
class NoGapBorder implements Border  {

    private final Insets insets = new Insets( -1, -1 , -1, -1 );

    /** 
     * Defines in Border interface.
     * @return The default insets instace that specifies no gap at all.
     */
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c ) {
        return insets;
    }


    /** 
     * Defines in Border interface.
     * @return false always, it is not relevant.
     */
    public boolean isBorderOpaque() { 
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Paint the border for the button. 
     * This creates the difference between setting the border to null 
     * and using this class. 
     * It only draws a line in the top, a line in the bottom and a 
     * darker line 
     * in the left, to create the desired effect.
     * A much more complicated strtegy could be used here.
     */
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, 
                            int x, int y, int width, int height) { 

       Color oldColor = g.getColor();
       int h = height;
       int w = width;

       g.translate(x, y);

        // Color for top and bottom
        g.setColor( c.getBackground().brighter() );

        // draw top line
        g.drawLine(1, 0, w-2, 0);

        // draw bottom line
       g.drawLine(0, h-1, w-1, h-1); 

       // change the color to make it look as a division
       g.setColor( c.getBackground().darker() );

       // draw the left line
       g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, h-2);        

        // set the graphics back to its original state.
       g.translate(-x, -y);
       g.setColor(oldColor);

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Dave Carpeneto wrote:

> **Oscar>***Unfortunately this stops working once you UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); , and this was also core to my needs (I'm looking to make this look as native as possible).*

Well, I was not trying to make your work, but to answer to your question, you thought your problems had to do with LayoutManagers and I said that was not the problem.

Perhaps I should've stopped there, but my "programmer" itch make me continue with the sample. : )

I'm glad you've solve your problem at the  end ;)

Comment: </quote> Perhaps I should've stopped there </quote>       Reely, reely glad you didn't - I learned quite a lot from the code you presented - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

For a really good explanation of how layout managers work, check out an old article I wrote at Sun

http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/GUI/AWTLayoutMgr/

It's old, but talks about preferredSize and layout nesting pretty well.

Enjoy,
-- Scott

Answer (score 0):

Hiya - thanks everyone for your assistance.

**Dan >** it was your comment about preferred layout that got me to get this working - adding `j0.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32, 32));` was all that was needed to get this to work.

**Oscar >** Unfortunately this stops working once you `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` , and this was also core to my needs (I'm looking to make this look as native as possible).

For example, here's what mine looks like with 3 buttons on XP:

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/8595/minems5.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/8595/minems5.png)

... and here's what yours looks like with the XP look:

[alt text http://img102.imageshack.us/img102/5412/yoursod4.png](http://img102.imageshack.us/img102/5412/yoursod4.png)

... which unfortunately isn't the same thing - sorry for not being clearer in my requirements :-(

FWIW, here's the code (images are transparent icons the same size as the buttons, with the vertical lines as part of the icon):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FunkyButtonLayout {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
          UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("x");
    Container y = frame.getContentPane();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    y.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JPanel uberButton = new JPanel();
    uberButton.setLayout(null);
    uberButton.setSize(98, 32);
    uberButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(98, 32));

    JButton record = new JButton(new ImageIcon("img/record.png"));
    record.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 32);
    record.setEnabled(true);
    record.setFocusPainted(false);
    JPanel _record = new JPanel();
    _record.setLayout(null);
    _record.setBounds(0, 0, 33, 32);

    JButton pause = new JButton(new ImageIcon("img/pause.png"));
    pause.setBounds(-4, 0, 44, 32);
    pause.setEnabled(true);
    pause.setFocusPainted(false);
    JPanel _pause = new JPanel();
    _pause.setLayout(null);
    _pause.setBounds(33, 0, 33, 32);

    JButton stop = new JButton(new ImageIcon("img/stop.png"));
    stop.setBounds(-4, 0, 36, 32);
    stop.setEnabled(true);
    stop.setFocusPainted(false);
    JPanel _stop = new JPanel();
    _stop.setLayout(null);
    _stop.setBounds(66, 0, 32, 32); 

    _record.add(record);
    _pause.add(pause);
    _stop.add(stop);

    uberButton.add(_record);
    uberButton.add(_pause);
    uberButton.add(_stop);

    y.add(uberButton);

    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

**Scott>** I have been schooled :-)  thanks